# PrimeFaces 7 p:fileUpload event not firing in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I have a form with a p:fileUpload. I'm able to choose a file but when I want to upload it, FileUpload event is not firing. I see nothing on server console. My project is a SpringBoot application and I don't have a web.xml file. I added spring.primefaces.fileuploadfilter property to application.properties file as below. I also have commons-fileupload-1.2.2 and commons-io-1.4 jars in my referenced libraries. I'm using primefaces v7.

This is my .xhtml code:

```
<p:fileUpload label="Choose"
                                                                    style="font-size:120%" uploadLabel="Upload"
                                                                    cancelLabel="Cancel"
                                                                    fileUploadListener="#{corporationBean.handleFileUpload}"
                                                                    mode="advanced" update="messages,filePanel"
                                                                    multiple="true" sizeLimit="104857000"
                                                                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|txt|ppt|pptx|msg|xml|rar|zip)$/" />
```

and this is my event method:

```
@Controller(value = "corporationBean")
public class CorporationController{
    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
         byte[] file = event.getFile().getContents();

         System.out.println("Do anything you want.");
    }
}
```

application.properties file:
spring.primefaces.fileuploadfilter=true

I tried add property to application.properties file. I also added the needed commons-fileupload-1.2.2 and commons-io-1.4 jars to project.